# How to access bookmarks from theme's Velocity template in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, velocity, bookmarks

How to access bookmarks from theme's Velocity template in Liferay?

I am accessing bookmarks with the code like

```
target_bookmark = BookmarksEntryLocalServiceUtil.getBookmarksEntry(Long.parseLong(target_bookmark_id.toString()));
```

from portlet java code.

How to do similar thing from within Veocity code of a theme?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have bookmarkId available in theme, you can use the following snippet in your velocity template of the theme

```
#set($bookmarksEntryLocalService= $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.bookmarks.service.BookmarksEntryLocalService"))

#set($target_bookmark = $bookmarksEntryLocalService.getBookmarksEntry(bookmarkId))
```

More info can be found in the following link

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+to+Liferay+services+in+Velocity

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but can you see if you do like this if($target_bookmark), does it check for null and then only process. Otherwise use $validator.isNotNull($target_bookmark)